# Can Airport Extreme host a standing VPN connection?

Tags: vpn

I'm not sure how to word this to even google if this is possible even without an Airport Extreme, but my network has the AE providing network services to it.  What I want to do is have the AE establish the VPN to another network so that the computers behind the AE just think the remote VPN computers are available.

In other words, from my mac at home, I can easily VPN to work.  But I'm looking to have the AE do the VPN connection, so that I don't have to manually set it up on my computer each time.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Airport Extreme does not provide any VPN services.